# OpenApi 3.0 Exclude Internal api definition

Tags: openapi, swagger-php

We have a requirement to generate multiple definitions of an API using the Php annotations.

While generating api spec(json/yml), need to exclude internal api which we should not expose to outside world.

And i  am using swagger to generate the api doc.

is there any possibility in OpenApi 3.0  and swagger?
can we name api as internal and external and exclude based on this tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger-php doesn't provide filtering, a solution is to use an external tool like [openapi-filter](https://github.com/Mermade/openapi-filter) to remove the internal api's from the generated spec.